# Select All Checkboxes in Table JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am displaying images in table using JScript code. There is a checkbox with each image. I have another checkbox to select/unselect all images. But I am having difficulty to write select/unselect logic using jquery/JScript. Here is my code:

`HTML:`

```
<table>
        <tr id="display-list">
        </tr>
</table>
```

`JScript/JQuery`:

```
function showImage(source, id) {
var list = document.getElementById("display-list");

//Image
var cellImage = document.createElement("td");
var objImage = document.createElement("img");
objImage.classList.add("obj");
cellImage.setAttribute("align", "center");
cellImage.setAttribute("valign", "bottom");
cellImage.appendChild(objImage);
list.appendChild(cellImage);

//Checkbox
var cellCheckbox = document.createElement("td");
var objCheckbox = document.createElement("input");
objCheckbox.id = id;
objCheckbox.type = 'checkbox';
cellCheckbox.setAttribute("valign", "bottom");
cellCheckbox.appendChild(objCheckbox);
list.appendChild(cellCheckbox);

objImage.src = source;
}
```

The HTML of Select All checkbox is as follows:

```
<div id="SelectAll">
            <input type="checkbox" title="Select All Images" />
</div>
```

Please help to write select/unselect function. Thanks

Comment: Where is the code for checkbox changes??

Comment: Also you tagged it with jquery, yet your code does not use jquery in any line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all checkboxes are inside the row with id `display-list` then try

```
$('#SelectAll input').change(function(){
    $('#display-list input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked)
})
```